# Multilateration with complex signal behavior

Tags: optimization, algorithms, physics, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the TDoA Multilateration problem, in three dimensions. That is, given the coordinates of 4 receivers in 3D space, the velocity of some signal, and the time at which each receiver "saw" the signal, I want to determine the coordinates of the signal source. To sum things up:

**Known:**

Coordinates of 4 observers (call them `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`)

Time of arrival of signal at each observer (call them $t_A$, $t_B$, $t_C$, $t_D$).

Velocity of the signal (call it $v$).

**Unknown:**

Time of signal emission (call it $t_i$)

Coordinates of signal source (call it $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$).

---

**My Problem:**

This is, in general, not a trivial problem so solve. It can, of course, be described by a nonlinear system. Many "standard" methods, however, quickly fail (Newton's method, etc.). My case is *further* complicated by the following:

In my specific situation, the signal in question is a *light* signal moving through a medium with a "complex" index of refraction. That is, the velocity of light depends upon depth, following the function:

$$n = 1.3 + 0.5(1 - e^{-0.02d})$$

Where $n$ is the index of refraction, and $d$ is depth.

For a simple refractive index, $n = \frac{c}{v}$, where $c$ is the speed of light (in a vacuum), and $v$ is the speed of light in the medium.

The goal here is to implement an algorithmic solution (i.e. in code), so as to process a large amount of signals quickly, determining the coordinates of each signal source as efficiently as possible.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I change notations since yours at not very clear to me.*

I worked this problem many years ago with the problem of sound velocity in deep water (my code was working on-line and had to be very fast).

Normally, for the observer $i$, the equation  write
$$\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2 }=v_i(Z)\, (t_i-T)$$ where

- $(X,Y,Z)$ are the coordinates of the source
- $T$ is the time at which the signal emitted
- $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ are the coordinates of the  observer $i$
- $t_i$ is the time at which the  observer $i$ received the signal
- $v_i$ is the average (in the integral sense) of the velocity of the signal between the source and the observer

This makes four variables $(X,Y,Z,T)$ and I am not sure that four observers would be sufficient (except if there is absolutely no noise).

After trying many things without success, I decided to use the following iterative procedure : fix the velocity at a given value and solve the  problem. From the results, update the $v_i(Z)$ and repeat again and again until the system stabilizes.

**Edit**

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640893/is-it-possible-to-define-the-position-of-a-gunshot-using-and-array-of-microphone/1642768#1642768), everything as based on the fact that, for observer $i$, the equation was
$$(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2 =\big[v_i(Z)\, (t_i-T)\big]^2$$ while, in fact, we want is to minimize
$$\text{SSQ}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \Big[\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2 }-v_i(Z)\, (t_i-T)\Big]^2$$ which is a "bit" different.

For convenience, I shall note $D_i=\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2 }$

So, now, in order to polish the solution (and this step is important), we need to solve for $(X,Y,Z,T)$ the four equations
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial X}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X-x_i) (D_i-v_i(Z) (t(i)-T))}{D_i}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial Y}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(Y-y_i) (D_i-v_i(Z) (t(i)-T))}{D_i}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial Z}=\sum_{i=1}^n (D_
i-v_i(Z) (t_i-T)) \left(\frac{Z-z_i}{D_i}-(t_i-T) v_i'(Z)\right)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial T}=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(Z) (D(i)-v_i(Z) (t(i)-T))=0$$

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks! The question now is, how do I solve this system in practice? I've tried solving this problem before, except with a constant signal velocity, using Newton's method, but it failed to converge (I'd almost always end up with a singular matrix in the "update" step, before coming to a solution).

Comment: @KeithMadison. How do you generate the starting values ?

Comment: At first, I picked random points, which failed (is there a better way?). Then, to test the algorithm, I generated some "simulated" signals (I picked some point in space, and used Pythagoras to calculate the time of arrival at each receiver, and fed this to the algorithm). Then, knowing the coordinates of the "simulated" signal source (since I created it artificially), I fed the algorithm starting values very close to these coordinates, and still often failed to get a solution (the algorithm would move start by moving closer to what I knew to be the correct solution, but then start diverging).

Comment: @KeithMadison. Have a look at my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640893/is-it-possible-to-define-the-position-of-a-gunshot-using-and-array-of-microphone/1642768#1642768 and come back

Comment: @KeithMadison. My linked answer is not finished. We should discuss later about the last step.

Comment: I've looked at the linked answer. I'm interested now in the last step.

Comment: @KeithMadison. Edited. Please, let me know how it works for you.